# ¿Identificar las posiciones que ocupa el valor 5 sin necesidad de recorrer todos los elementos.?

Tags: javascript

pues tal y como pone en el titutlo como se sacan todos los valores por pantalla, se que hay que usar el **indexOf** para sacar la posicion que ocupa pero solo soy capaz de sacarlo con el primer 5 , el resto no se porque no me los lee, quiza no entiendo el codigo o no entiendo lo que hay que hacer. Aqui va el codigo que tengo hecho hasta el momento:

```
function myFunction() {
    var numeros = [4,0,3,4,8,5,3,1,4,8,4,3,2,6,1,8,9,7,8,5,0,1,5]; 
    var a = numeros.indexOf(5);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
  }
```

Comment: Me lo piden asi, pero es que no termino de entenderlo, y ademas quiero sacar la posicion de todos los 5 de ese array.

Comment: El comentario de @ArnauCastellví no es totalmente cierto. indexOf pernite usar un segundo parámetro para hacer búsquedas interiores. Te dejé una respuesta con un ejemplo.

Comment: @quevedo está en lo cierto.

Answer (score 1):

No has comprendido aún la sintaxis del método `array.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])`

Debes tener presente que puede tener un segundo argumento ***fromIndex*** que indica la posición a partir de la cual empieza la búsqueda dentro del array. Ese argumento es cero cuando no se pasa de modo que inicia la búsqueda en la primera posición.

Una vez lo encuentras debes repetir la búsqueda a partir de la posición inmediatamente siguiente. En tu código a+1.

Ejemplo:

```js
var numeros = [4,0,3,4,8,5,3,1,4,8,4,3,2,6,1,8,9,7,8,5,0,1,5];
var salida = 0;
while(salida > -1){
    salida = numeros.indexOf(5, salida);
    if (salida > -1) { // si encuentra otra ocurrencia la muestra.
        console.log('posición: '+salida);
        salida++; // se incrementa para buscar desde la posición siguiente
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva.
referencia: [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf)